# Get applicants from Table 1 and compare id and get user details from Table 2 Using PHP

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Ok so I have two Tables

1. Applicant list -  this shows all applicants

[image]

2. User Table

[image]

Now I'm Providing `news_id` by Post method  and I want to list details of all `users(email,mobile,username)` where the value for  *user_authToken* and *user_authtoken* is same. Can Someone help me out with this logic using **PHP**.

```
       $job_id = $_POST['job_id'];
       $resultSet = $con->query("SELECT appliers_list.news_id  AS jobid ,
       appliers_list.user_authToken AS user,
       user.user_name AS username,
       user.mobile AS mobile,
       FROM appliers_list,user 
       WHERE  appliers_list.news_id = '$job_id'
       ORDER BY appliers_list.id DESC
       ");
       $rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: Isn't this just a simple join using the `user_authtoken` columns?

Comment: i tried but it's listing all the results in table

Comment: Show what you tried so we can see what you did wrong and help you fix it.

Comment: I've edited what i tried , check my query and please tell me what i'm doing wrong

Comment: You forgot to join with the `user` table, obviously.

Comment: You're selecting from 2 tables but you're not specifying how the 2 tables should join.  You need something in your WHERE clause which says something along the lines of ```table1.column = table2.column```

Comment: Also, string concatenation is a really bad way to build SQL queries because it leaves your code wide open to SQL injection.  http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all, your naming is very inconsistent, it's hard to read and understand.
- Second, please use prepare statement, otherwise you open your system to SQL injection.

  ```
  $news_id = $_POST['job_id'];

  $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT email, mobile, user_name
  FROM users 
  WHERE user_authtoken in (select user_authToken from appliers_list where news_id = ?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $news_id);
  $stmt->execute();
  $resultSet = $stmt->get_result();

  while($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
  // data manipulation here
  }
  ```

Comment: If i had to get one  more value from column , 'profile_url' from another table `tbl_profile` where the common value is as 'user_authoken' and combine all result?

Comment: Then you should use `join` to join 3 tables

Answer (score -1):

you can use left join to get record from both table :

```
       $job_id = !empty($_POST['job_id']) ? intval($_POST['job_id']) : 0;
       $resultSet = $con->query("SELECT appliers_list.*,users.email
       FROM appliers_list 
       left join users on appliers_list.user_authToken  = users.user_authToken
       WHERE news.news_id = '$job_id'
       ORDER BY news.id DESC
       ");
       $rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: Why left join instead of inner join?

Comment: i think there can be multiple news from same user so our aim is to derive primary data is news,then user detail is secondary

Comment: inner join will return multiple rows. The only difference with left join is that it will return news news items with no matching user.

Comment: Yes, they both show records from both tables. But left join will also show records that aren't in both tables.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't specify a relationship between the `user` and `appliers_list` tables, so you're getting all rows in `user`. You also have an extra comma at the end of the `SELECT` list.

```
   $job_id = $_POST['job_id'];
   $resultSet = $con->query("SELECT appliers_list.news_id  AS jobid ,
   appliers_list.user_authToken AS user,
   user.user_name AS username,
   user.mobile AS mobile
   FROM appliers_list
   JOIN user ON appliers_list.user_authToken = user.user_authToken
   WHERE  appliers_list.news_id = '$job_id'
   ORDER BY appliers_list.id DESC
   ");
   $rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc();
```